# Expanding $e^{1/z}$ in Laurent expansion around the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

I know $e^{1/z}$ expands to $e^\frac1z=(\frac1z+\frac1{2!z^2}+\frac1{3!z^3}+\cdots)$ within a proof it states that they used this to show $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos\theta}\cos(\sin\theta-n\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{n!} \quad (n \ge 0) $$

Now I have been looking at this and I was trying to manipulate it to complete the proof but I cannot get it to work out.

Comment: Are you sure that the integral is not from $0$ to $2\pi$ ?

Comment: Yes you are correct the integration should have went to $2\pi$. I thank you for your solution I will run with that in hope to complete the proof. Thanks for your help @C.Dubussy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know by Laurent's theorem that, if $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n z^n,$$ then $$a_n =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$$ where $C_r$ is a small circle around $0$. Now apply this to $e^{\frac{1}{z}}.$ Of course we have $a_{-n} = \frac{1}{n!}$. Hence $$\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C_r} e^{\frac{1}{z}}z^{n-1} dz.$$ Now, use the parametrization $t \to (r\cos(t),r\sin(t))$ to evaluate this integral and conclude.

Comment: Laurent's theorem aka. the Fourier series theorem

Comment: Excuse me, how is it that you perform the integral with this parametrization to arrive at the result? I’ve been trying, but not getting anywhere. Please i would really appreciate your help