# Use the Laurent series to prove that $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{\cos(t)} \cos(nt-\sin t)\,dt=\frac{2 \pi}{n!}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Need help to demonstrate the next integral

$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{\cos (t)} \cos(nt-\sin t)\,dt=\frac{2 \pi}{n!}$,  $n=0, \pm 1,...$

I have tried using Laurent’s development of $e^{1/z}$, but i have not managed to prove it.

Now, i have to

$$\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C_r} e^{\frac{1}{z}}z^{n-1} dz.$$

I have tried to use the parameterization of a circle, but i have terms that do not correspond to my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding $e^{1/z}$ in Laurent expansion around the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733604/expanding-e1-z-in-laurent-expansion-around-the-origin)

Comment: More or less, is that i do not know how to calculate the integral to conclude the exercise. Could you help me please?

Comment: I would suggest that you update the question accordingly: Describe what you already know and what you tried.

Comment: Ready, thanks!!

Comment: So what do you get when you parameterize $z(t) = e^{it}$ in the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is your choice of contour, $|z|=1$ with $z:=e^{it}$, obtains $\oint z^{j-1}dz=2\pi i\delta_{j0}$, so$$\oint z^{n-1}e^{1/z}dz=\oint\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{k!}z^{n-k-1}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}.$$